# Ext - Ajax.request / Api.restActions?

Tags: extjs, store

I am using Ext Js with Rails. I have implemented CRUD functionality, wherein I used Ext.Ajax.request for Insert and restActions for Update. Any suggestions as to which one is better - using Ext.Ajax.request or 
Ext.data.Api.restActions ??

Below is the code for reference :

```
//** Insert - ajax.request **//

btnSave.on('click',function(){
   var unitname =  Ext.getCmp('unitname').getValue();
   var description =  Ext.getCmp('description').getValue();
          Ext.Ajax.request({
          url: '/units',
          method: 'POST',
          params: {'data[unitname]':unitname,'data[description]':description}
          });
          grid.store.reload();
          grid.show();
          myform.hide();
         });

    //** Update - restActions **//

    Ext.data.Api.restActions = {
                //create  : 'POST',
                //read    : 'GET',
                update  : 'PUT'
                //destroy : 'DELETE'
                };
    btnUpd.on('click',function(){
                  var store = Ext.getCmp('maingrid').getStore();
                  store.save();

                 }); //end update
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Internally, both end up as Ajax calls to your server. In case of REST calls, the appropriate HTTP methods are used. Where as when you code the Ajax requests you may use POST for update & insert.

I can think of two factors here:

1. **Repetitive Code:** If you application is big and complex. The Ajax.request will become repetitive code and increase the lines of code.
2. **RESTful API:** If you plan to build a RESTful application, the best option is to make use of Ext.Direct.

I am not sure why you choose to use a mix of these two methods! If you are making use of the REST concepts, you can do the CRUD using the Ext.Direct. I would not recommend a combination for CRUD.

Since you are already using the REST, why don't you use the REST completely?

Comment: Thanks a lot! Actually I had implemented using ajax request and a friend suggested REST so wanted to know the difference ! :)